# How to modify the jump character color displayed by evil-avy-goto-line?

Tags: help

The color of the jump character displayed by `evil-avy-goto-line` is somewhat blurred, which causes me to change the color of the displayed character or modify the color of the background strip of the character.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first character:

```
(set-face-attribute 'avy-lead-face-0 nil :background "green" :foreground "yellow")
```

Second character is avy-lead-face-1 and third is avy-lead-face-2

Comment: Thank you very much,This is great

Comment: My avy installation required me to change `avy-lead-face`, `avy-lead-face-0` and `avy-lead-face-2`. There was no `avy-lead-face-1`.